# In Kotlin where should I define a reusable callback in a class?

Tags: android, kotlin, callback

I want to use this callback as a method parameter in my class.
In order to avoid duplication at the moment I'm just declaring it in a local variable but I'm not sure this is a best practice.
What's the best way to achieve this?

```
private val callback = object : ActionMode.Callback {

        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            mode?.menuInflater?.inflate(R.menu.items_contextual_action_bar, menu)
            isInActionMode = true
            return true
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

            return when (item?.itemId) {
                R.id.action_delete -> {
                    DeleteItemsDialogFragment().show(childFragmentManager, DeleteItemsDialogFragment.TAG.toString())
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?) {
            isInActionMode = false
            tracker?.clearSelection()
            actionMode = null
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean = false
    }
```

Comment: This is the cleanest, most concise way to do it.